# Saving belongstomany relations in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now, and I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. I have the following 3 Tables where a retailer has many clients, and clients can have many retailers, which is a belongstomany relations in CakePHP 3. The relations between the 2 are stored in the clients_retailers table.

```
class ClientsTable extends Table
{
        ...
        $this->belongsToMany('Retailers', [
            'joinTable' => 'clients_retailers'
        ]);
}

class RetailersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...

        $this->belongsToMany('Clients', [
            'joinTable' => 'clients_retailers'
        ]);
    }
}

class ClientsRetailersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('clients_retailers');
        $this->displayField('client_id');
        $this->primaryKey(['client_id', 'retailer_id']);

        $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Retailers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'retailer_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
            ]);
        }
}
```

Then in the Client controller's add function I am trying to save this relation between a new client and the retailer.

```
 public function add()
        {
            $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $retailer_id = $this->Auth->user('retailer_id');
                $retailer = [
                    'retailers' => [
                        [
                            'id' => $retailer_id
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data);
                $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $retailer, ['associated' => [
                        'Retailers'
                    ]]);


                if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The client has been saved.'));
                   return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
        }
```

The new client is never added to the database. I saw online that it could have been a validation problem so I tried using  `['validate' => false]`, but it did not seem to change anything. The save function simply fails with no errors.

What is worst is that this relation used to be saved correctly when called from another function in the api controller. I tried copying it of course, but it does not seem to work in this controller. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be. Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:
Here is the client entity value that I am trying to save

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Client) {

    'firstname' => 'test',
    'lastname' => 'test',
    'email' => 'test@email.com',
    'password' => 'hash',
    'retailers' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Retailer) {

            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'TestRetailer',
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                'time' => '2017-12-20T20:13:58+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

                'time' => '2017-12-20T20:13:58+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false

            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true,
                'id' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Retailers'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'firstname' => true,
        'lastname' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'retailers' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Clients'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. I had a beforeFind behavior on the find function of the Clients' table and I did not realized that this was causing the saving to fail

Answer (score 0):

You need a change in your code for working,

```
public function add()
        {
            $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $retailer_id = 'XXXXXX'
                $retailer = [
                    'retailers' => [
                        [
                            'id' => $retailer_id
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data, ['validate' => false]);   //Validation false
                $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $retailer, ['associated' => [
                        'Retailers' => ['validate' => false]   //You need to disable validation here too
                    ]]);


                if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The client has been saved.'));
                   return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried this but I still get the same problem. I believe the problem occurs in the save function and might be related to the client entity, which I updated the question with the debug value of.

Comment: I can help you more if you post the table structure of table Clients and Retailers. (Try this pr($client->errors());die;  before save())

Comment: I updated the question with the tables structure, so I hope this will help.I also put the value of the client object from the debugger. As for the $client->error, it returns an empty array.